# How to generate unspendable testnet bitcoin address with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a testnet address. However, I tried to write this python program (using help of various online code places), and I created this program. The program is designed to take a 20 byte input and then turn that 20 bytes of data into an address by putting the version byte (`6f`), the meat of the data (the 20 bytes being added into the code), and the checksum. However, it didn't work.

```
# *-* encoding: utf-8 *-*

import hashlib, codecs, sys, base58, bytes, base64
def checksum(inPut):
# Double SHA256 to get checksum
    sha256_nbpk = hashlib.sha256(inPut.encode())
    sha256_nbpk_digest = sha256_nbpk.digest()
    sha256_2_nbpk = hashlib.sha256(sha256_nbpk_digest)
    sha256_2_nbpk_digest = sha256_2_nbpk.digest()
    sha256_2_hex = codecs.encode(sha256_2_nbpk_digest, 'hex')
    return (str(sha256_2_hex)[2:-1])[:8]

x = "6f"+"64"*20
x += checksum(x)
print(str(base58.b58encode(str(base64.b16decode(x.upper()))))[2:-1])
```

Comment: This is a great idea. Did you find a solve? Maybe you'd have to have your own fully isolated 'new' bitcoin system , eg a set of dockers? I'm just guessing since I know little.